# How to disable wordpress cron jobs for a subsite?

Tags: multisite, wp-cron

Is there a way to disable the execution of all the cron jobs of a particular subsite in a wordpress multisite installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this filter does the trick:

`add_filter('schedule_event', '__return_false');`